# Confusion about xml file encoding

Tags: ruby, xml, encoding, nokogiri

I'm working on replicating the generation of an xml file currently output by a legacy system.

Here is what the XML I'm trying to replicate looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<DESCRIPTION>&#1052;&#1054;&#1044;&#1059;&#1051;&#1068;- ELECTRONIC  OUTPUT 120 V DC 5 mA</DESCRIPTION>
```

However when I generate the xml with nokogiri using the encoding 'UTF-8' this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DESCRIPTION>МОДУЛЬ- ELECTRONIC  OUTPUT 120 V DC 5 mA</DESCRIPTION>
```

When I generate the xml with nokogiri using the encoding 'ASCII' this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
      <DESCRIPTION>&#1052;&#1054;&#1044;&#1059;&#1051;&#1068;- ELECTRONIC  OUTPUT 120 V DC 5 mA</DESCRIPTION>
```

The content of the Description node is encoded the way I want, but now the processing instruction node does not match the file I will be replacing.

Why would I only be able to get the desired output encoding with an encoding different from what my target format is?

If I am posting this to an external app for processing will the processing instruction matter or will the fact that the data is encoded properly be enough?

Any light that can be shed would be great.

Comment: UTF-8 and ASCII are exactly the same in this case, why does it matter?

Comment: It matters because I wanted to make the xml the same as what the old application was sending, to avoid problems during the migration. But the settings I am having to use won't let me have UTF-8 processing instructions and have the strings properly escaped. Is it ok to ignore the processing instruction encoding and just ensure that the data strings are correct?